# PGAdmin - user has no delete rights?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

either way how I grant my user rights to the db, it fails to `DELETE FROM mySchema."MyTable";`

I have assigned `ALL PRIVILEGES` to my user through the PGAdmin UI -> right click Database / Schema -> Properties -> Security

and the UI shows my user has `UC` privileges. However, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` fail with permission issues. Same queries work with the admin account.

```
grant all privileges on database "MyDB" to "MyUser";
grant all privileges on schema MySchema to "MyUser";
```

Still no success. This would have worked with MySQL / MariaDB. What am I missing?
(Select works)

Comment: What you are missing is not reading the docs. Read [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html). You will find that you are doing what you think you are. In Postgres schema and database are different things not like MySQL where they are the same thing.

Comment: `ALL` is fairly limited for database and schema permissions. And these don't give you any permission on any other type of object, like a table. Most likely you want to change the default permissions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: The question is missing the actual error message.